# squelize and sqlite concat two column and place conditional in where on that

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

```
this.User.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', [sequelize.literal("firstname || 
        ' ' || lastname "),"
        fullName "],"
        fullName "],where:  {
          fullName: {
            [Op.like]: '%' + searchData + "%"
          }
        }
      })
```

//SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: fullName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same literal in `Sequelize.where` to achieve your goal:

```js
this.User.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', [sequelize.literal("firstname || 
        ' ' || lastname "),"
        fullName "],"
        fullName "],
  where: Sequelize.where(sequelize.literal("firstname || 
        ' ' || lastname "), Op.like, '%' + searchData + '%')
      })
```